# Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000005

Tags: android-studio

When iam trying to launch Virtual Device in Android studio, it shows the following Error.

Unable to detect ADB version, exit value: 0xc0000005

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kokZe.png see image

Comment: In the Android studio , I use Java, and in the Event log section at the bottom, I see this error, and I always have this error. Please help as shown in the above picture link.

Comment: please give answer